# Mule dataweave transformation

Tags: mule, dataweave

I have below json as my input payload and I want to fetch groupvalue where groupname is b. How to do this in dataweave ?

```
[
  {
    "groupName": "a",
    "groupvalue": "1234"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "7890"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure there is only one element in the array with groupName equal to "b":

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload filter ($.groupName == "b") map ( $.groupvalue)) [0]
```

With your input I get the following output:

```
"7890"
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error when I run the same.                                                              Message : "You called the function 'filter' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("" as String {encoding: "UTF-8", mediaType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"...)
  2: Function (($:Any, $$:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Array
  2: Function

Comment: It looks like in your case it is receiving as payload an empty string instead of the array, (..."" as String...). How are you testing it?

Comment: Yeah I got the issue, payload was going as null, so it was failing. There is a csv file which has some name value pair. I want to fetch value on the basis of name. Can you help with this.

Comment: Please open a new question for the CSV issue and provide the details.

Answer (score 0):

In case, there are a number of key, value pairs for groupName "b", this code will give you an array of the groupvalue for groupName "b"s.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload filter ((item, index) -> item.groupName == "b"))["groupvalue"]
```

For example:

```
    payload = [
  {
    "groupName": "a",
    "groupvalue": "1234"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "7890"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "8330"
  }
]
```

You will get:

```
[
  "7890",
  "8330"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, there are a number of key, value pairs for groupName "b", this code will give you an array of the groupvalue for groupName "b"s.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload filter $.groupName =="b").*groupvalue
```

example:-

```
payload = [
  {
    "groupName": "a",
    "groupvalue": "1234"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "7890"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "8330",
    "groupvalue": "1234"
  }
]
```

example 2

```
payload = [
  {
    "groupName": "a",
    "groupvalue": "1234"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "7890"
  },
  {
    "groupName": "b",
    "groupvalue": "8330"
  }
]
```

script:-

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload filter $.groupName =="b")..groupvalue
```